# Docker Swarm, can I get all hostnames from within one of the containers?

Tags: docker, swarm

I am using docker swarm to launch 4 replicas and was trying to get the hostnames of all the machines from within one of the containers.

```
docker service create --name web-service --replicas 4 --network overlay-network -p 8080:8080 test-image:latest
```

I know I can get the hostnames on the host machine by running `docker ps` but I would like to  find all hostnames running in the swarm from within the containers themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but if so, it is likely to be complicated and to be avoided. Clusters are all about stateless ephemeral containers/pods. If you get a list of hostnames and one gets re-scheduled, what then? If you need to talk to all other containers, it doesn't sound stateless. Might be better to ask the question around what you are trying to ultimately achieve, because there might be a better way.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you will expose an API that gives you the desired info, which you will trigger from your within your container.